# Problem installing pandas for use with python in rstudio markdown

Tags: python, r, pandas, rstudio

Inability to install pandas into rstudio.
I have tried:
library(reticulate)
options(reticulate.conda_binary = "C://Users//ch120187//Anaconda3")

py_install("pandas")

Elsewhere on my computer, pandas works just fine, and I originally loaded python using Anaconda3.
To use python on rstudio, I invoked r-miniconda at one point.

from the rstudio python prompt, i have tried to type:

> > > import pandas as pd

and it returns:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'gzip' has no attribute 'open' (most likely due to a circular import)

It does not list pandas or pd in the Values section of the Rstudio environment pane, unlike functional packages like numpy

see previous screen:
pd is not recognized using help(pd);
it returns /python/pd.html not found.

help(numpy) in contrast calls up the help documentation for numpy.